# Trapping regions in higher dimensional dynamical system?

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

Consider a continuous-time dynamical system defined by
$$
\dot{x}=f(x), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^{n},
$$
where $f$ is sufficiently smooth, $f(0)=0$.

Is is possible to determine the existence of a trapping region when $n>2$? I am not asking for the general behavior of an orbit inside the potential trapping region (whether it goes to a fixed point, goes to a limit cycle or neither) I am asking what would be the criteria for a trapping region to exist?

Comment: One criterion you will find frequently in exercises is $x^Tf(x)<0$, either everywhere or outside some ball, for $|x|>R$.

Comment: Thank you, could you perhaps share an example or redirect to a reference?